# Инициализация View в классе Activity

Tags: android, оптимизация, инициализация

Пытаюсь инициализировать `View` через метод `findViewById()`, прямо в классе `MainActivity`, чтобы затем, при многократном использовании одного и того же `View` через `onClick`, метод `findViewById()` не вызывался много раз, но при инициализации прямо в классе `MainActivity` приложение вылетает.

Что я делаю неправильно и как можно один раз инициализировать `View` для всех последующих методов?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    

public View customView = (View) findViewById(R.id.btn);

public void onCustomClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn:
            customMethod(customView);
            break;
        // и т.д.

    }
}

private void customMethod (View customVar)
{
    // тело метода 
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`findViewById` должно вызываться например в `onCreate()` методе активити. Т.е. оставьте `public View customView;` а в onCreate добавьте:

`customView = (View) findViewById(R.id.btn);`

UPD. Если копнуть глубже то в `Activity` у вас в самом начале метода `onCreate()` есть вызов `setContentView()`. Это именно этот вызов инициализирует разметку для `Activity` и только после того как он отработал можно вызывать `findViewById()`.

UPD2. Диаграмма жизненного цикла `Activity`, спасибо @hardsky за идею, см. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html

[image: activity lifecycle]

Таким образом, исходя из диаграммы, провести инициализацию можно в:  `onCreate()` после setContentView(), в методах `onStart()` и `onResume()`.

Comment: можно в ответ еще добавить ссылку на диаграмму про жизненный цикл Activity https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle

Comment: @hardsky была такая мысль, но подумал что автор не оценит. Тут еще по хорошему надо расписать про порядок инициализации полей статических, инстанса и конструкторов.

Answer (score 3):

Ссылки на элементы разметки из .xml будут доступны после того , как этот .xml пройдет инфлейт (inflate) - преобразование из декларативного языка разметки в объекты виджетов. После такого преобразования мы можем получить ссылку на какой либо объект `View` по его `id` , заданному в разметке, с помощью метода `findViewById()`.

Следует различать две разных реализации этого метода:

`Activity.findViewById()` - данный метод будет возвращать ссылки на объекты виджетов из разметки только после применения метода активити `setContentView()` , который свяжет указанную в методе разметку с отображаемым на экране и проведет инфлейт этой разметки в объекты.

`View.findViewById()` - данный метод вернет ссылку на объект виджета по его `id` , если виджет с таким `id` присутствует в `View`.

При этом данный `View` может быть создан динамически - из кода, и тогда ему вообще не требуется инфлейт из XML-разметки , так как мы сразу получаем объекты виджетов, либо пройти инфлейт из XML-разметки отдельно от метода `setContentView()` , с помощью метода класса `LayoutInflater` - `getLayoutInflater()` и метода  `inflate()`.
Стоит заметить , что увидеть на экране полученные таким образом `View` можно будет только после того , как они будут добавлены в разметку , которая указана в методе `setContentView()`:

```
//контейнер Layout1 присутствует в разметке , подключенной методом setContentView()
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout1);

//контейнер view1 содержит TextView text1 и будет добавлен в контейнер Layout1
  LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
  View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view1, layout, false);
  TextView text = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.text1);
  text.setText("Hello");

  layout.addView(view1);
```

`view1` и `text1` изначально не присутствуют в разметке , подключенной методом `setContentView()` , мы добавляем ее самостоятельно позже , так же устанавливаем значение одному из ее виджетов и только потом переносим в основную разметку , отображаемую на экране

---

Для того, чтобы ссылка на объект (а `View` это тоже объект в глобальном понимании) была доступна для всех методов в пределах класса (а `Activity` это тоже класс , в глобальном понимании) необходимо сделать ссылку на этот объект `полем класса`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    
 View customView;
 ...
}
```

В коде к такому `полю класса` следует обращаться только по его имени , без указания класса:

```
//Правильное обращение к полю класса.
  customView =(View) findViewById(R.id.customView);
  customView.setText("Hello");

//Неправильное обращение к полю класса.
//Данный код создаст ЛОКАЛЬНУЮ переменную с именем, аналогичным имени поля класса ,
// но она никак не будет связана с полем класса 
  View customView =(View) findViewById(R.id.customView);
  customView.setText("Hello");
```

---