# Метод findViewById() не возвращает объект View

Tags: java, android

Есть такой код.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button button;
    EditText editText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }



    public void click(View v){
        String city = editText.getText().toString();
        String geoUriString = "geo:0,0?q="+city+"&z=8";
        Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(geoUriString);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
```

Суть проста. Нажимаем кнопку, получаем текст из `EditText` и ищем на карте. Я не могу получить текст в `EditText`. Когда начинаю отлаживать, пишет что ссылка в `EditText = null`. Получается ошибка где то в строке `editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)`, хотя в шаблоне id прописан верно.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findViewById()` должны быть после `setContentView()`

[Подробности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419701/177345)