# Таймер обратного отсчёта

Tags: android, countdowntimer

Помогите разобраться! Не работает код, не могу понять почему.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/go"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="#FF3D00"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/Start"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> 


    package com.example.android.myapp;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;


    public class Step5 extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button mgo;
    public TextView timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.step5);
        timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        mgo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go);

        mgo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new CountDownTimer(900000,1000) {
                @Override

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    timer.setText((int)millisUntilFinished/1000);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    timer.setText("Done");

                }
            }.start();
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: `timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);` должно быть после  `setContentView(R.layout.step5);`.

Comment: @post_zeew Не хочет...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/422803/177345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именно в этом куске кода должно быть так:

```
    private TextView timer;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.step5);
            timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
        }
```

Comment: Activity запустилась, спасибо, НО не реагирует на нажатие кнопки старт. Вроде кнопка прописана как и все предыдущие, но почему-то не хочет работать.

Comment: ну так а где создание объекта Button и привязка его к разметке? И где обработка нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: @ded-logoped, код step5.xml покажите

Comment: @woesss Добавил код кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Для сплешей использовал такой кусок кода, может поможет

```
int time = 4000;//время обратного отчета (4с)

Thread Timer = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int logoTimer = 0;
                while(logoTimer < time) {
                    sleep(100);
                    logoTimer = logoTimer + 100;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);//где Activity - нужное вам активити
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    Timer.start();
```

еще нужно определить кнопку, например

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
```

+ нужно обработать клик в onCreate, например

```
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTimer(v);
            }
        });
```