# Для чего приведение к типу в методе findViewById()

Tags: java, android, ооп

Изучаю ANDROID, вот пример листинга:

```
Button newMyBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
```

Синтаксически запись правильна, только я вот одного понять не могу, зачем здесь вот это самое приведения объектной ссылки? Что, нельзя в объект **newMyBtn** сразу положить вызов метода **findViewById**?

Я почитал Хорстаманна и нашел (но все равно остался непонятен принцип данного приведения):

> Чтобы выполнить приведение объектной ссылки, используются такие же
>   синтаксические конструкции, как и для числовых выражений. Имя
>   требуемого класса надо поместить в скобки и поставить перед объектной
>   ссылкой, которую нужно преобразовать. Пример соответствующего
>   выражения приведен ниже.
>
> ```
> Manager boss = (Manager) staff[0];
> ```
>
> Для приведения типов существует только одна причина — необходимость
>   использовать все возможности объекта после того, как его фактический
>   тип был на время забыт. Например, в классе ManagerTest массив staff
>   представляет собой массив объектов Employee. Этот тип выбран,
>   поскольку некоторые элементы массива хранят информацию об обычных
>   сотрудниках. Чтобы получить доступ ко всем новым полям класса Manager,
>   нам может понадобиться привести тип некоторых элементов массива к типу
>   Manager. (В примере, рассмотренном выше, мы предприняли специальные
>   меры, чтобы избежать приведения типов. Мы инициализировали переменную
>   boss объектом Manager, перед тем как поместить ее в массив. Для того
>   чтобы задать размер премии, нужно знать правильный тип объекта.)

Comment: Насчет литературы - Б.Харди "Программирование под android" 2014, очень толковая книжка. Еще Рето Майера почитайте, инженер гугл по андроид все же

Comment: Понял, спасибо :)

Comment: Немного [информации по методу `findViewById()`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419701/177345), для расширения кругозора, раз затрагивалось в комментариях к ответу. Насчет "никто не ответил" - люди здесь не 24/7 торчат, иногда и поспать надо :)

Comment: Спасибо, ознакомился

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Проблема в различии двух вещей: декларируемого и фактического типа объекта.

Дело в том, что метод `findViewById` не может знать, что по данному `id` будет лежать именно `Button`. Поэтому он декларирует тип возвращаемого объекта как `View` — это максимальная гарантия, которую он может дать. Фактически возвращённый объект может быть любого производного от `View` типа.

Итак, у нас `findViewById` возвращает `View`, который, как мы уверены, фактически будет `Button`'ом. Для того, чтобы работать с ним как с `Button`'ом, мы должны иметь ссылку типа `Button`. Мы её декларируем: `Button newMyBtn`.

Теперь, у нас инициализация ссылки типа `Button` другой ссылкой, у которой декларируемый тип — всего лишь `View`. Система не уверена в том, что фактическим типом будет `Button`. Для того, чтобы убедить её в этом, мы используем приведение к нужному типу `(Button)findViewById(...)`.

Эта конструкция фактически означает: «Я уверен, что фактический тип объекта будет `Button` или производный от него. Причём настолько уверен, что согласен крешнуть программу, если это не так.» (Точнее, выбросить исключение, да.) При этом компилятор соглашается с вашими доводами, и приводит декларируемый тип `View` к `Button`. (Если во время выполнения там реально будет не `Button`, вы таки получите исключение.)

Без приведения вы не убедите компилятор, что тип у ссылки правильный.

Почему для компилятора важно убедиться в правильности типа? Потому что если у вас ссылка `newMyBtn` имеет заявленный тип `Button`, то вы можете у неё вызывать методы, специфичные для `Button`'а, и обращаться к полям, которые есть в `Button`'е. Если этот объект окажется фактически другого типа, и таких полей в нём не будет, что тогда? Компилятор заботится о том, чтобы таких ситуаций не возникало. (Это называется словом «типобезопасность».)

Comment: Ого, сильно конечно, спасибо за полноту ответа, с первого раза не все понял, еще раз прочту

Comment: все понял ) спасибо, ключевое то здесь "findViewById не может знать, что по данному id будет лежать именно Button"

Comment: Тогда вопрос: А где же определен метод findViewById? что его можно просто так, взять и вызвать...

Comment: Вы молодец! Очень сильно разбираетесь в терминологии :) Не каждый так сможет ответить!

Comment: @Артёмыч: Это [метод класса `Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29). Он определён, если вы наследуетесь от `Activity` (внутри класса-наследника).

Comment: @Артёмыч: Спасибо! :)

Comment: не подскажите литературу по ANDROID? :)

Comment: @Артёмыч: Я не специалист, но у нас есть список литературы тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416635/10105. Может быть, в нём найдётся что-нибудь интересное для вас.

Comment: @Артёмыч: Хм, хотя в том списке ничего про конкретно Android не видно :(

Comment: НЕ СПЕЦИАЛИСТ!? Да кроме вас, здесь никто больше и не ответил, видимо "Ок, гугл!" уже не тот )))

Comment: Вот ещё список: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/135019/10105

Comment: @Артёмыч: Не, у нас есть спецы по Java куда круче. Просто их в этот момент не оказалось на сайте. Вот наши лучшие специалисты по Java/Android: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/100/android, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/93/java.

Comment: Да, KoVadim мне тоже как-то помогал с ответами! Я вам всем конечно же очень благодарен, я никого не хочу обидеть, просто бывают люди, которые кидают ссылки на гугл, с такой уверенностью, что неужели человек обращаясь за помощью уже не один день бьется над проблемой!

Comment: @Артёмыч: У нас посылать в гугл больше не принято :) Вот обсуждение на Мете: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/10105

Comment: А ну вот пожалуйста, только вспомнил очень толкового и смешного одессита Deonis, с языка сорвали, там как раз и от него комментарий )))